# Viterbi Decoder - How does inverting the input bits affect the result?

Tags: channelcoding, viterbi-algorithm

Does converting zeros into ones and ones into zeros in the input stream affect the decoding result? Empirically I have seen that it does not affect, decoding $[0 1 0 1 \ldots]$ and $[1 0 1 0 \ldots]$ produce the same output stream. But I am not sure if it is true or not, and I am looking for a theoretical proof.

Why I am doing this is because the convolutionally encoded stream (rate $\frac{1}{2}$ and constraint length 7) is received without the phase information, thus a conversion is needed. I am trying to determine in which step I should convert the data.

I would appreciate if you could share any knowledge.

Comment: Yes, inverting the bits changes things.  For a better test of this, feed it all 0's and then feed it all 1's.

Comment: @Jim Clay I might have asked my question wrong. Simply, does `invert(viterbi(data))` produce the same result as `viterbi(invert(data))`? Thanks by the way, you saved my life many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convolutional codes are linear in the Galois{2} (i.e. binary) field.  We know this because the convolution operation is linear.  The fact that Viterbi codes are linear has a few implications.  First, if you input all 0's you will get all 0's out.  Second, if you add two inputs together the output will be the sum of their individual outputs.

The last piece of information that we need for a very informal "proof" is that when you input all 1's the output is all 1's (EDIT: this is not always true- see the edit at the bottom of the answer).  We see that this must be so because the encoder state is constant (you are, after all, inputting all 1's) so the output must be constant.  The output cannot be 0's because that would match the all 0's case which would make the code non-linear (other than in the trivial case where the encoder always outputs 0 no matter what the input is).

Now that we've established that inputting all 1's causes the output to be all 1's we can prove that yes, inverting the input is equivalent to inverting the output.

$$
Input => Output\\
Input + Ones => Output + Ones
$$

If we assume the first statement then the second statement follows due to linearity and all 1's producing all 1's, with the understanding that binary inversion is equivalent to adding 1.  0 + 1 = 1, 1 + 1 = 2 = 0.

EDIT: Dilip is correct.  For some generator polynomials an all 1's input will produce an all 1's output and so inverting the input is equivalent to inverting the output.  For some generator polynomials, though, an all 1's input will *not* produce an all 1's output, so inverting the input is *not* equivalent to inverting the output.  The generator polynomials that do produce an all 1's output have odd Hamming weights for both polynomials.  The reason that Dilip's polynomial does not meet the criteria is that one of the polynomials ($1 + x^2$) has an even Hamming weight.

EDIT 2: Dilip makes a valid point that even polynomials with odd Hamming weights will produce some zeros at the beginning while the zeros in the state memory are shifted out and replaced with ones.  This is relatively brief, but it does mean that the inversion equivalence does not hold during that time.  It does hold during the "steady state" behavior.

Comment: I don't think the argument about an all-ones input producing an all-ones output is correct. Consider, for example, the simple _ad nauseam_ code with generator $$G(x) = [1 + x^2, 1 + x + x^2]$$ for which an all-ones input produces output $$11~ 10~ 01 ~01 ~01 \cdots $$

Comment: @DilipSarwate  You're right.  I've edited the answer.

Comment: "The generator polynomials that do produce an all 1's output have odd Hamming weights for both polynomials." The odd weight requirement might be necessary but is it sufficient? Consider the (systematic) code with $$G(x) = [1, 1+x+x^2]$$ where both polynomials have odd Hamming weight. The response to all-ones must be $$11~ 10~ 11 ~ 11 ~ 11 \cdots$$ right?

Comment: @DilipSarwate  Yes, there is at the very beginning a blip when you are shifting out the initial zeros in the state memory.  I was talking about the steady state behavior.

Comment: "I was talking of the steady-state behavior" OK, but do you have _any_ example of a nontrivial convolutional encoder for which complementing the input bit sequence results in the _entire_ output getting complemented, not just the steady-state part? If so, could you please incorporate such an example into your answer?  Thanks.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I understand from your conversation that the linearity holds, and the only important thing is that whether the decoder produces all-ones for an input of all-ones. I think my case fits this since the polynomials are g1=171 and g2=133 (octal), so I can invert the bits before or after the decoding block. Please inform if I'm wrong.

Comment: @groove In the steady state your generator polynomials will produce all 1's, but Dilip makes a valid point that at the beginning they will produce some zeros, so the inversion equivalence does not hold at the beginning.